# Shuffling array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf=8" />
        <title>Blackjack</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="blackjack.css" />
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
            var H2 = 2; var S2 = 2; var D2 = 2; var C2 = 2;
            var H3 = 3; var S3 = 3; var D3 = 3; var C3 = 3; 
                
    
            
            var deck = new Array(H2, S2, D2, C2, H3, S3, D3, C3);
            
            var new_deck = new Array();
            
            var r;
            
            document.write("deck = ")
            
            for (r =0; r<deck.length; r++){
                document.write(deck[r]);
                }
                
            document.write("</br>")
                
            document.write("new deck = ")
            
            for (r=0; r<new_deck.length; r++){
                document.write(new_deck[r]);
                }
                
            document.write("</br>")
            
            for (r=0;r<deck.length;r++){
                var randomindex = Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length);
                new_deck.push(randomindex)
                deck.pop(randomindex)
                }
                
            document.write("deck = ")
            
            for (r =0; r<deck.length; r++){
                document.write(deck[r]);
                }
                
            document.write("</br>")
                
            document.write("new deck = ")
            
            for (r=0; r<new_deck.length; r++){
                document.write(new_deck[r]);
                }
                
            document.write("</br>")
                
            
        </script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Obviously this isn't the full Blackjack game here. It's just a test to see if shuffling the array works by printing the contents of both decks (arrays) before and after the shuffle.

I'm only using 8 cards at the moment, 4 2's and 4 3's.

What I am getting from this is:

> deck = 22223333
> new deck =
> deck = 2222
> new deck = 7502

What I'm hoping to get is:

> deck = 22223333
> new deck =
> deck =
> new deck = 23232323 (or any of the 8 numbers, generated randomly)

So it should be shuffling those 8 cards, what am I doing wrong?
I'm only new to JavaScript but I've used some python before. I've done something similar in python and worked perfectly, but I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `new_deck` just contains indexes, not values and you aren't removing the previously chosen values before you choose the next random value.  `.pop()` does not take an argument so you can't remove a specific index with it - you would have to use `.splice()` for that.  All in all, you aren't getting a new array of your values for several reasons.

If you just want an easy way to randomize an array without reinventing the wheel and knowing that the randomness actually works well you can use this:

```
function fisherYates ( myArray ) {
  var i = myArray.length;
  if ( i == 0 ) return false;
  while ( --i ) {
     var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
     var tempi = myArray[i];
     var tempj = myArray[j];
     myArray[i] = tempj;
     myArray[j] = tempi;
   }
}
```

You can read about the Fisher-Yates method here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle.

You can read about why some other randomization methods don't work as well you can read here: http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html.

So, you would replace this:

```
       for (r=0;r<deck.length;r++){
            var randomindex = Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length);
            new_deck.push(randomindex)
            deck.pop(randomindex)
            }

        document.write("deck = ")

        for (r =0; r<deck.length; r++){
            document.write(deck[r]);
            }

        document.write("</br>")

        document.write("new deck = ")

        for (r=0; r<new_deck.length; r++){
            document.write(new_deck[r]);
            }
```

with this:

```
        document.write("deck = ")

        for (r =0; r<deck.length; r++){
            document.write(deck[r]);
            }

        document.write("</br>")

        document.write("shuffled deck = ")

        // shuffle the deck and then output it
        fisherYates(deck);

        for (r=0; r<deck.length; r++){
            document.write(deck[r]);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly. Now that it works, I'll have to look into that Fisher Yates function and understand it fully, and also learn the differences between all the array methods. I think now it might take longer than i thought to create this Blackjack game, but I'll carry on anyway

Comment: one question: what does 'while ( --i )' mean?

Comment: @DennisCallanan - `while (--i)` means to decrement `i` and if the result is truthy (e.g. not-zero), then keep going with the `while` loop.  If the value of `i` is zero after the decrement, then stop the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Another super easy array sort technique:

```
 deck.sort(function() { return Math.random()-0.5})
```

Comment: I'm a bit worried about this - although it looks great, it would have the possibility (Depending on the sort being used, I think) for it to never return? JavaScript probably uses a sort that this won't apply to, as they're usually the fastest, mind.

Comment: The function passed to sort is supposed to return a consistent result for any two values, not a random result.  This is potentially troublesome.

Comment: Apparently it's not that great: http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html

Comment: Interestingly enough, the recommendation in that article is the Fisher Yates shuffle which is what I used in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to change your shuffle for this:

```
while(deck.length > 0 ){ //for loop won't work
    var randomindex = Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length);
    new_deck.push(deck[randomindex]);//Move onto new stack
    deck.splice(randomindex,1); //Take from old.
}
```

Here's why the for loop won't work:
Say `deck.length = 4`

Start of the for loop: `r = 0`

One item is pushed onto new stack & popped: `deck.length = 3`

`r` is incremented `r = 1`

`r` is less than `deck.length`, continue

One item is pushed onto new stack & popped: `deck.length = 2`

r is incremented `r = 2`

`r` is no longer less than `deck.length`, the loop has finished but only half the elements where transferred!

Comment: pop doesn't take an argument.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Right you are, fixed

Comment: What's funny is, I had the same thing you had typed out on my phone since I was on the bus. Someone else corrected me, and I couldn't get the "edit" button to work so I just deleted it. Have an upvote.

Comment: @JoeFrambach +1 for the sad story. hehe :P

Answer (score 0):

you are getting a random value, not a random index into the deck

```
for (r=0;r<deck.length;r++){
    var randomindex = Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length);
    new_deck.push(deck[randomindex]);
}
```

Comment: This will cause duplicates in the new deck.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem begins in the `for` loop where you randomize the deck. You need to create a new variable *before* the loop containing the deck's length. See:

```
for (r=0;r<deck.length;r++){
    var randomindex = Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length);
    new_deck.push(randomindex)
    deck.pop(randomindex)
}
```

What you have going on here is that `r` increases by 1 at the same time as `deck.length` is *decreasing* by 1 (due to the `pop` in the `for` loop). So, that's why you're only getting four "cards" in your shuffled deck. The second problem is that you're not `push`ing a card into the new deck, you're `push`ing the `randomindex` itself.

This code should do the trick:

```
var i = deck.length;
for (r=0;r<i;r++){
    var randomindex = Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length);
    new_deck.push(deck.splice(randomindex, 1));
}
```

(P.S.: Originally, neither of your statements in the above `for` loop had semicolons at the end.)

**Edit:** You could also use a `while()` loop. See [meiamsome's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17409804/2038227).

**Edit 2:** As Joe mentioned below, `pop()` doesn't take an argument. `splice()` does what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: pop doesn't take an argument.

Comment: You could also do `for(var r = deck.length; r > 0; r--)`

Comment: As per @JoeFrambach, you should replace `deck.pop(randomindex)` with `deck.splice(randomindex, 1)`, just in case you were stuck.